# How do I disassemble ABC bytecode?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, bytecode

If I have an abc file, either compiled through the flex SDK, or stripped from a .SWF file, are there any tools that will disassemble that file purely to see what it contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download free Adobe Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK). Use `sdk/bin/swfdump.exe`.

Example for windows version:

```
swfdump -abc -showbytecode test.swf > abcdump.txt
```

This should get you what you want.

Comment: Where can I get help about options I can used with swfdump?

Comment: I have no idea, actually. Typing `swfdump` in console yields the following: `Usage: java tools.SwfxPrinter [-encode] [-asm] [-abc] [-showbytecode] [-noactions] [-s
glyphs] [-external] [-save file.swf] [-nofunctions] [-out file.swfx] file1.swf ...` It's not much, but the names are quite self-explanatory, if you know what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't played much with abc, but one thing that comes to mind is [as3abc](http://github.com/jcheng/as3abc).
Maybe if you load the abc in binary format using and URLLoader and passing the bytes to the ABC constructor you can see what it contains(actionscript-wise)

Also, there might some tools for that in [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/), not sure.
I've got an abc file using dump, but haven't gone any further.

```
java -jar dump.jar -input a.swf -abc
```

You can have a look at the contents with any text editor.

HTH,
George

Answer (score 1):

The tamarin source contains a tool called 'abcdump' which will decompile an abc file, but you're generally on your own building and using it.  It's not kept up to date and comes with few to no instructions.

For SWF files, there is a tool called 'swfdump' available from [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) which will give disassembly of actionscript in the swf.

Answer (score 1):

[RABCDAsm](https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm/) can disassemble and assemble back ActionScript 3 bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I can only vouch for furnace. We have had huge success with it! See: https://github.com/whitequark/furnace-avm2

It works like a charm with raw bytecode (eg. ABC files without any SWF containter)

Josh